# SpringBoot integration test - TestRestTemplate doesn't reach controller and get 404 instead of 200

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, resttemplate, mockmvc

I was trying to play a little bit with integration test in springboot, hence I build some sample test using `@SpringBootTest` annotation. My sample test is :

```
     @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
     @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
     @ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestConfig.class)
        public class WeatherForCityIT {


            @Autowired
            private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;



            @Test
            public void getWeatherForExistingCity() throws Exception {

                String existingCity = "London";

                ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("/weather/{cityName}",String.class,existingCity.toString());
                Assertions.assertThat(responseEntity).isNotNull();


            }
        }
```

And have following controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/weather")
public class ChartController {

    private WeatherForecastAPI weatherForecastAPI;

    @Autowired
    public void setWeatherForecastAPI(WeatherForecastAPI weatherForecastAPI) {
        this.weatherForecastAPI = weatherForecastAPI;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{cityName}")
    public List<WeatherForecastDTO> get5daysForecast(@PathVariable String cityName) {

        weatherForecastAPI.getWeatherForecastByCity(cityWithCountryCode.toString());            
    }

}
```

Unfortunately in response body I get message 404 Not Found. In debug mode I see that it never reaches defined controller. Am I missing something from configuration perspective ? I was trying to also use MockMvc :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestConfig.class)
public class WeatherForCityIT {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getWeatherForExistingCity() throws Exception {

        String existingCity = "London";

        restTemplate.getForEntity("/weather/{cityName}",String.class,existingCity);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/weather/" + existingCity))
               .andDo(print())
               .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }
}
```

but also without success (again 404 instead of 202).

**EDITED**

Configuration class looks following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class IntegrationTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration configuration() {

        return com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.builder()
                                                .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider())
                                                .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
                                                .options(EnumSet.noneOf(Option.class))
                                                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking at your code, request mappings look fine. What you could do is to check for available mappings in your test context. Autowire **RequestMappingHandlerMapping** in your **WeatherForCityIT** test class, and access the mappings with `RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getHandlerMethods().keySet();`. Check if _/weather/{cityName}_ path is in this list.

Comment: Thanks Igor, I've checked this and I received `No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping' available`, this leads me to that, I haven't paste here full code. I miss `@ConfigurationContext ` wich point to empty configuration class. When I delete this, then everything works fine. Why is that ? Why specifying configuration class cause that error ?

Comment: With `@ContextConfiguration` you specify what `@Configuration` classes to load to configure your **ApplicationContext** in your tests. Usually you don't need it when testing Spring Boot applications. `@SpringBootTest` will automatically search for you primary configuration in class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`. If you need to adjust your primary configuration, it's better to use `@TestConfiguration` class. You can find out more [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html).

Comment: Ok, but how to deal with not nested configuration. This configuration class is common for a lot of other test, so I don't want to copy paste it to other classes. Because `@TestConfiguration` is for nested configuration

Comment: Try annotating your **IntegrationTestConfig** with `@TestConfiguration` instead of `@Configuration`.

Comment: Do I need to also define usage of this class in some special way in my test class. Im asking because i was trying to do this but without success

Comment: Have you tried `@SpringBootTest(classes = {IntegrationTestConfig.class}, ...)` or `@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestConfig.class)` as in your sample code?

Comment: Yes, I've tried both,, but withou success.In both cases configuration is not loaded (exception No qualifying bean of type 'com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: getConfiguration,configuration). I've updated my question with my configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in your test configuration class. Therefore **IntegrationTestConfig** should look like:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class IntegrationTestConfig {

    @Bean
    public com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration configuration() {

        return com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.builder()
                .jsonProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider())
                .mappingProvider(new JacksonMappingProvider())
                .options(EnumSet.noneOf(Option.class))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Your **WeatherForCityIT** should remain as in you sample code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
     @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
     @ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestConfig.class)
public class WeatherForCityIT {
     // your code here...
}
```

---

Regarding the exception message you are receiving:

> No qualifying bean of type 'com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: getConfiguration,configuration)

From the error message you know that you have **2 beans** of the same type (`com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration`) in your context:

1. Bean with name **getConfiguration**
2. Bean with name **configuration**

The bean **configuration** is defined in your *IntegrationTestConfig*, the other bean **getConfiguration** is defined in one of your configuration classes. Somewhere in your application you are autowiring 'com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration' bean by type. Since you have 2 beans of this type, Spring is complaining with the exception.

Do you need both of these beans? If not, delete one of the beans. Otherwise consider using [@Qualifier](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) annotation when autowiring beans.

Comment: I think that its right solution for my issue. Just to summarize - `@ContextConfiguration (classes = IntegrationTestConfig.class)` needs to refer `@TestConfiguration` class, otherwise `@Configuration` class would override my main configuration from application. Now, `@Qualifier` is not the best in my case - it is integration test, hence autowiring take place in buisness method, not test method. But with profiling I can achieve the same effect. Even more, then I don't need to define @ContextConfiguration, as it doesnt help with bean amibguity problem. Thank you for help @Igor !